# couchbase query date ranges

Tags: time-series, couchbase, date-range

I have an existing relational data model with effective and expiration dates. some records have an explicit expiration date, other records have a null expiration date, which means they are effective indefinitely. It is important to query this dataset and get back objects that fit within the effective/expiration dates. I am looking to migrate this data to couchbase.

I've seen some couchbase view creation strategies that create indexes on date when effective and expiration dates are both defined,  but i don't quite know how to visualize this when the expiration date is indefinite? would this be a situation where i would need to rebuild the view daily and add records for "current date" until the records with no expiration date are updated to expire by the user?

Ultimately, i'm trying to determine if i can even create a view on this data and if so, what would the logic for it look like?

Any help you could provide would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Couchbase 4.1 and then consider using N1QL with global secondary indexes (GSI). You can represent your dates using strings in the ISO-8601 format, create indexes on your dates, and then issue queries using N1QL. N1QL allows you to query for both non-null and null values, and also provides several datetime functions. You will not need to manipulate your null dates in order to query them.